# Y Axis on Bar Chart in Excel has three equal data points, but should have only 1

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have a chart in Excel from this data

```
                September-17    March-18    April-18
Division Work       1                   0            0
On-Wing Work        0                   1            1
```

The chart should have on the Y-axis 0 as a data point and 1 as a data point. However, my Y-axis is showing three zeros and three ones vertically. [Chart Shown Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I21BX.jpg) . I have tried manually entering the data and making sure that the data was not rounded, but none of this has made a difference. How can I re-create this bar chart so that there is only a single Y-value for each data point? I am also curious to know why Excel would be doing this?

Comment: Do you want a bar chart instead?

Comment: I plan to use columns for Division Work and the line graph for On-Wing Work

Comment: I think you might actually be getting all of the data plotted.  The problem is that with a column chart, there is nothing to see when the value is zero.  Can you mock up what you want it to look like (you can use crayons on a napkin just to give us the idea of what you're looking for).

Answer (score 0):

Your axis numbers are rounded. Here's how to fix them

1) Select the Y-axis, right-click and choose "Format Axis..."

[image]

2) Under Format Axis, expand the NUMBER options

3) Make sure you have "Number" selected under category and 1 (or more) decimal places

[image]